# Batch process throwing future method error

Tags: apex, batch

I have a scheduled job that executes a batch process that clones some opportunity records. When the records are inserted, it fires triggers on the opportunity that calls a future method, which throws the `Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method`. I could bypass the error by check `if(!isBatch()){...`

However, I need the trigger code to run and the method has to run async. What options are there to overcome the error and still have the future method run?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/201931/2995

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/205297/2995

Comment: You are already in an async process and can therefore make callouts without using a method annotated `@future`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queueable can be called from Database.Batchable classes. You must go through enqueueJob for this to work:

```
public class BatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] records) {
    System.enqueueJob(new QueueClass(new Map<Id, Account>(records).keySet()));
}
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
}
```

}

```
public class QueueClass implements Queueable {
Set<Id> recordids;
public QueueClass(Set<Id> recordIds) {
    this.recordIds = recordIds;
}
public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
     // Do something here
}
```

}